# can't set my tableView cells after clicking on TabBarButton

Tags: swift

My application has a TabBarViewController with two items: one button's title is "RICHIESTE" and the other one is "IN VENDITA". When I click on this two buttons I execute the following instructions:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if(item.title == "RICHIESTE"){

        let myUrl = NSURL(string:"http://chuadiv.ddns.net/easytoschool/fetch_book_user_request.php");

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        let postString = "mail=\(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userEmail") as! String)";
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
        MenuViewController.requestBooksArray.removeAll()

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil{
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            var err: NSError?

            do{
                var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray


                if let parseJSON: NSArray = json {

                    for index in 0...parseJSON.count-1 {

                        if (parseJSON[index] is NSNull){
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Attenzione\n", message:"Nessun libro trovato", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

                                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in }

                                myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                                self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
                            }
                        }else{
                            let libro = parseJSON[index] as! [String:Any]
                            print("\n\n",index,":\n")

                            let book = requestBook.init(bookId: libro["id"] as! String,bookName: libro["name"] as! String,bookAuthor: libro["author"] as! String,bookPrice: libro["price"] as! String,bookStatus: libro["status"] as! String,bookISBN: libro["isbn"] as! String,bookType: libro["type"] as! String,bookIdRequester: libro["idRequester"] as! String,bookNameRequester: libro["nameRequester"] as! String,bookSurnameRequester: libro["surnameRequester"] as! String,bookMailRequester: libro["mailRequester"] as! String,bookNumberStatusRequester: libro["numberStatusRequester"] as! String,bookRequestedOn: libro["requestedOn"] as! String)

                            book.printBook()

                            MenuViewController.requestBooksArray.append(book)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch{
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume();

    }else{
            let myUrl = NSURL(string:"http://chuadiv.ddns.net/easytoschool/fetch_book_user.php");

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL);
            request.httpMethod = "POST";
            let postString = "mail=\(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userEmail") as! String)";
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
            TabBarViewController.sellBooksArray.removeAll()

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil{
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                var err: NSError?

                do{
                    var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray


                    if let parseJSON: NSArray = json {

                        for index in 0...parseJSON.count-1 {

                            if (parseJSON[index] is NSNull){
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Attenzione\n", message:"Nessun libro in vendita", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

                                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in }

                                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                                    self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
                                }
                            }else{
                                let libro = parseJSON[index] as! [String:Any]
                                print("\n\n",index,":\n")

                                let book = sellBook.init(bookId: libro["id"] as! String,bookName: libro["name"] as! String,bookAuthor: libro["author"] as! String,bookPrice: libro["price"] as! String,bookStatus: libro["status"] as! String,bookISBN: libro["isbn"] as! String,bookType: libro["type"] as! String,bookAddedOn: libro["addedOn"] as! String)

                                book.printBook()

                                TabBarViewController.sellBooksArray.append(book)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }
            }
            task.resume();
    }
}
```

After doing these instructions I want to set my two TableViews according to the button.
I can't do it because when I click on the button in the TabBarController it goes immediately to the TableView and then executes the instructions so it doesn't set any row.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a `UITabBarController` which contains two `UITableViewController`, so if the anyone taps onto a specific `tabBarItem`, you then execute a specific api request and present that data into its tableView? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, in this UITabBarController there are two items that redirect both to a different UITableViewController. I take data from a .php file and then I want ti display It in the UITableViewController. The problem is that when I click the item, It goes immediately to the UITableViewController and then executes the instructions. In this case the array that should be full of data, is plenty

Comment: I hope you unterstand

Comment: I think your problem is not that the tableview shows up early, but there is no data to be shown or placed inside of it. The code that you have above inside of `didSelect`, you should place it inside of your tableView `viewDidLoad()` also have a spinner or indicatorView animating while your request is getting the data, once there is no error and you have the data, on the `main queue` append your array, reload your tableView and stop the spinner.

Comment: There is data in the array because I print the array with the function printBook and there is a book in my array

Comment: I tried to put the code in viewDidLoad() but It doesn't show a row with a book like with the solution above

Comment: now the question is, did you correctly post request to  your api, is there a data coming back to you ?

Comment: Yes, it returns the right data

Comment: good && then you know that you can't to this   `MenuViewController.requestBooksArray.append(book)` if you move the code to MenuViewControoler

Comment: I think that you didn't understand my problem; sorry, maybe I explained it bad